# Radiobutton Selected value not pass to the controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 radio buttons with mvc view.When i do form submit that Checkboxes values not pass to the controller.

I have a form submit like this,

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Index","Employee",FormMethod.Get))
{
    <b>Search by :</b>@Html.RadioButton("Searchby", "EmpName",true)<text>Name</text>
    @Html.RadioButton("Searchby", "IsPermanant")<text>Id</text><br />
    @Html.TextBox("Search");
   <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}
```

I have a controller

```
public ActionResult Index(string Search, bool Searchby)//In here searchby is null
{

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your creating a radio button group that will post back either the value `"EmpName"` or `"IsPermanant"`, yet you are trying to bind it to a `boolean` property.

Either change the parameter `bool Searchby` to `string Searchby` or change the radio buttons to return `true` or `false`

Comment: What do you want to post back. It would make sense to post back the string ("EmpName" or "IsPermanant") so you can test `if (Searchby == "IsPermanent") { // do this } else { // do that }` in which case just change the parameter from `boolean` to `string`. Other wise you need `@Html.RadioButton("Searchby", true ,true)<text>Name</text>` and `@Html.RadioButton("Searchby", false)<text>Id</text>`

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to use the `FormMethod.Post` instead of `FormMethod.Get`

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Index","Employee",FormMethod.Post))
{
    <b>Search by :</b>@Html.RadioButton("Searchby", "EmpName",true)<text>Name</text>
    @Html.RadioButton("Searchby", "IsPermanant")<text>Id</text><br />
    @Html.TextBox("Search");
   <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}
```

The second parameter of method RadioButton is value you want to pass to your controller. In your example you are passing EmpName or IsPermanant as string but your controller is expecting boolean. Changing the controller to accept string would allow you to pass the values you have for radio buttons.

```
public ActionResult Index(string Search, string Searchby)
{

}
```